# Partial Derivatives of Spherical Angles and Refracted Ray w.r.t Surface u,v

Tags: rendering

I am reading on ["Specular Manifold Sampling"](http://rgl.epfl.ch/publications/Zeltner2020Specular) paper with the implementaion(for the simple case) [here on Mitsuba at github](https://github.com/tizian/specular-manifold-sampling/blob/master/src/librender/manifold_ss.cpp). As part of the calculation it needs to compute

1. partial derivatives of spherical angles w.r.t surface u, v. which is calculated in [this method](https://github.com/tizian/specular-manifold-sampling/blob/1f0e40342a8760450d5aa6202ea096feaa70256a/include/mitsuba/render/manifold.h#L430)

   Basically given a normalized vector `w(x,y,z)` and it's partial derivatives `dw/du` and `dw/dv` vectors, how do you calculate:

   `dtheta/du`,  `dtheta/dv` , `dphi/du` , `dphi/dv` ?  (theta and phi are spherical coords of w)
2. partial derivatives of refracted ray w.r.t surface u, v [implemented here](https://github.com/tizian/specular-manifold-sampling/blob/1f0e40342a8760450d5aa6202ea096feaa70256a/include/mitsuba/render/manifold.h#L384). ie. Given an incoming ray, surface normal and their partial derivative vectors w.r.t to surface u,v, what are partial derivatives of the refracted ray w.r.t u and v?

I guess it's using chain rule but I don't fully understand the math behind these two.

For example for the first case :
`dtheta/du = dtheta/dz . dz/du` and  `dtheta/dz` comes from derivative of `theta = cos^-1(z)` w.r.t `z`. But I don't understand how `dphi/du` is calculated.